# Can I run a MySQL script to install test data into database with maven

Tags: java, mysql, maven

Can I run a MySQL script to install test data into database with maven.

As my project is being build and tested I would like to run a script on mySQL database to install some data for testing and then from it after testing..

Can someone please let me know if this can be done

Comment: Normally done in the unit test setup method. That allows to run a single unit test / unit test method with stable results.

Comment: I'd recommend using dbunit: http://www.dbunit.org/